# Android Studio: Cleartext HTTP traffic to google.com not permitted

Tags: android, http, https

Before you mark this question as duplicate here me out.

I have added the `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` file and declared it in the `AndroidManifest` file but I am still getting this error:

```
Error while pinging URL: http://google.com. Cleartext HTTP traffic to google.com not permitted
```

`network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
</domain-config>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...
</application>
```

`Important points`:

I can't use `https` because its coming from a library that I am using. Facebook ad mediation library to be more specific.

When I use `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the manifest file instead of using `network_security_config` file it works.

Also when I use `base-config` instead of `domain-config` inside the `network_security_config` (of course I change the format to use base-config) then it also works.

But as many of the developers suggested, this is not a safe solution. Can anyone tell me if it is actually safe of not?

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Go through this link you'll find a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: I am coming here after reading all the comments there. They confused me, everyone saying different stuff. I need a solution for this specific case, which wasn't mention there.